# Pre-Installation Check Mantis: can't install

Tags: installation, mantis

I am trying to install Mantis on my server. Problem is that I can't seem to get pass the Pre-Installation Check step. I click on "Install/Upgrade Database", and displays all "GOOD". Then it says:
Database Creation Suppressed, SQL Queries follow
<< here it prints a lot of sql queries, mainly create and alter tables >>. When I say this the first time, I went to MySQL Workbench, (the database bugtracker was already created), and ran the script given. Thereby, creating all the needed tables.

Then it says:

```
Your database has not been created yet. Please create the database, then install the tables and data using the information above before proceeding.
```

It checks a few more things (all with result "GOOD") and finally it displays this message:

```
Install was successful.
Continue to log into Mantis
```

The previous word "Continue" appears as a hyperlink leading to login_page.php. When I click it, it leads right back to this pre installation check page.

The thing is, the database is created! And the first time I encountered the sql queries I ran them, so the tables are indeed created.

```
Attempting to connect to database as admin  GOOD
Attempting to connect to database as user   GOOD
Checking Database Server Version 
Running mysql version 5.5.25
```

My PHP version is 5.3.14.
The Mantis version i'm trying to install is 1.2.11.

Any ideas as in what it is I am doing wrong? Or any other piece of information I could provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now that this is not the best place for this question. Nonetheless, in case someone else happens tu stumble across this, I wanted to let know the only workaround I could find was installing another Mantis version: 1.1.1. Very old, but it worked!